# MySQL GROUP BY - exclude groups where values in a column differ within the group

Tags: mysql

I have a query like the following which returns concatenated chains of dates for each group:

`myTable` has columns `group_id`, `date`, and `region`

```
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(
             date
             ORDER BY DATE DESC SEPARATOR '<-'
) AS date_chain
FROM myTable
GROUP BY group_id
```

However I want to omit any group where there is more than one `region` value within that group. Is there a straightforward way to achieve this?

e.g. If we had

```
group_id | date | region
________________________
    1    | 2012 |  US
    1    | 2013 |  UK
    2    | 2010 |  US
    2    | 2014 |  US
```

we should get `2014<-2010` returned, but not `2013<-2012` because group 1 changes region

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94ee4a/1

```
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(
             date
             ORDER BY DATE DESC SEPARATOR '<-'
) AS date_chain
FROM myTable
GROUP BY group_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT region)<2
```